# How do I use Protocol Buffer messages kept in different .proto files?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to keep my proto message types separate like so,

In .proto file 1:

```
message A {
    repeated B b = 1;
}
```

In .proto file 2:

```
message B {
    optional bool b = 2;
}
```

I can't reference B from .proto file 1. Is this possible or am I using protobuffers incorrectly?